# Changing DataGrid Row Styles while adding Items

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, datagrid, datatrigger

I'm trying to change row style while adding items to DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" Margin="10,64,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UIvisibility}" Value="-2">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UIvisibility}" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UIvisibility}" Value="-0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

kMS(i).line(7) has "-2","-1","-0" or "1" for each kMS(i) as String, And will be assigned to Item.Visibility

For Instance

```
kMS(1).line(7)="-1"
kMS(4).line(7)="-0"
kMS(369).line(7)="1"
kMS(897).line(7)="-2"
```

Codes are following

```
Dim c3 As DataGridTextColumn = New DataGridTextColumn
c3.Binding = New System.Windows.Data.Binding("UIvisibility")
c3.Visibility = 1
datagrid1.Columns.Add(c3)

Dim Additem(kMS.Length - 1) As Item
For i = 0 To kMS.Length - 1
    Additem(i) = New Item
    Additem(i).Callback = kMS(i).line(8)
    Additem(i).Keyboard = "No Assign"
    If kMS(i).line(3).Remove(0, 2) <> "FFFFFFFF" Then
        Additem(i).Keyboard = kMS(i).line(3).Remove(0, 2)
    End If

    Additem(i).UIvisibility = kMS(i).line(7)

    datagrid1.Items.Add(Additem(i))
Next
```

```
Public Class Item
        Public Property Callback As String
        Public Property Keyboard As String
        Public Property UIvisibility As String
End Class
```

It's not working well and the result would be only rows with transparent background and black foreground.

[Actutal image of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9cOS.png)

What am I missing?

Comment: Okay, my problem was coming from Mahapps not allowing <Style.Triggers> works inside <Style.Triggers>. I could have change specific row color by disabling Mahapps style. I also could do the same thing with Mahapps enabled by referring [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526292/assigning-style-resources-to-a-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you post a screenshot of your problem.

My guess is that you change the property of the wrong WPF control. For changing the background, DataGridRow is ok only for the part of the row which is not covered by any row. This can happen when the DataGrid is wider than all columns together.

For the columns, DataGridCell, i.e. TextBox gets painted over the DataGridRow. So if the DataGridRow is transparent, but the TextBox  is white, you will see a white background.

This kind of problem WPF often avoids using graphical inheritance, meaning when a property is set in a container, all controls who don't write their own value for that property will inherit the value from the container.

Unfortunately, DataGrid behaves quite differently. Usually, your problems go away if you don't depend on graphical inheritance but style the correct control.

**2 Recommendations**

1) Don't use triggers to change the style. You can easily do it using bindings:

```
<datagrid.rowstyle>
  <style targettype="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
      Path=Item.Quantity, Converter={StaticResource QuantityToBackgroundConverter}}"/>
  </style>
</datagrid.rowstyle>
```

The Foreground could be done like this:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" 
  Value="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
    Path=Text, 
    Converter={StaticResource QuantityToForegroundConverter}}" />
```

2) Formatting the DataGrid is a major headache. I spent weeks trying to understand it. Read my article where I provide a lot of background information and many samples how important formattings can be done:

[www.codeproject.com: Guide to WPF DataGrid formatting using bindings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings)

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the OP. Columns number depends on how many game control devices are connected to the PC so sometimes it might be wider than DataGrid, however, it stays white background even they are not(like in the screenshot). I have referenced this code [link](http://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/20100519/1274273555) to change each Row color depends on "UIvisibility" property. I also downloaded your source code from codeproject.com and looking for a solution now. Thanks for the help.